# Python: How can you access an object or dictionary interchangeably?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, object

I'm writing a Django view that sometimes gets data from the database, and sometimes from an external API.

When it comes from the database, it is a Django model instance. Attributes must be accessed with dot notation.

Coming from the API, the data is a dictionary and is accessed through subscript notation.

In either case, some processing is done on the data.

I'd like to avoid

```
if from_DB:
   item.image_url='http://example.com/{0}'.format(item.image_id)
else:
   item['image_url']='http://example.com/{0}'.format(item['image_id'])
```

I'm trying to find a more elegant, DRY way to do this.

Is there a way to get/set by key that works on either dictionaries or objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [Bunch class](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch/1.0.0), which transforms the dictionary into something that accepts dot notation.

Comment: Just looked at its source, that's a slightly more polished version of my simple `AttrDict` (providing the correct `AttributeError` rather than `KeyError`, providing `__repr__` and `__delattr__` and providing a recursive conversion method). I doubt I'd ever have found it myself... "Bunch" seems a fairly non-descriptive name.

Comment: Thanks for knowing about/finding this class, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript they're equivalent (often useful; I mention it in case you didn't know as you're doing web development), but in Python they're different - `[items]` versus `.attributes`.

It's easy to write something which allows access through attributes, using `__getattr__`:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value
```

Then just use it as you'd use a `dict` (it'll accept a `dict` as a parameter, as it's extending `dict`), but you can do things like `item.image_url` and it'll map it to `item.image_url`, getting or setting.

Comment: Nice, good suggestion. I'm going to accept @Daniel's answer since he found/knew a complete class for this, but it should be cool since you got 7 upvotes, including mine. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, if you don't mind an extra dependency (or just want to pull it into the main tree), Bunch is a more accurate solution. Normally this would be sufficient but that one is more accurate (AttributeError instead of KeyError and providing `del` support in particular).  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the implications will be, but I would add a method to the django model which reads the dictionary into itself, so you can access the data through the model.

Comment: I haven't actually worked with customizing models much, so I have to admit I'm not sure what that means. Using `.values()` to get a ValuesQuerySet is another option, too, which would simply change the model object into a dictionary.